# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contains')

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple todo list app as part of an online tutorial by DevEd, but am getting stuck on one seemingly puzzleing error.

Using the following HTML markup:

```
<div class="todo-container">
  <ul class="todo-list"></ul>
</div>
```

.. alongside some javascript to create and insert some list elements, I'm then using the following function to filter by todo list entries that have a specific class tag.

```
function filterTodo(e) {
  const todos = todoList.childNodes;
  todos.forEach(function (todo) {
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "all":
        todo.style.display = "flex";
        break;
      case "completed":
        if (todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
          todo.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
          todo.style.display = "none";
        }
        break;
    }
  });
}
```

All the above seem to work together fine, until I added ANYTHING, even a comment line in between the `<ul></ul>` tags like below:

```
<div class="todo-container">
      <ul class="todo-list">
         <!-- boo -->
      </ul>
</div>
```

Upon doing this I get the following error when trying to filter the entries:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contains')
```

Can anyone please explain?

Full code found here:
https://github.com/developedbyed/vanilla-todo
(not my repo)

Comment: `childNodes` includes nodes that aren't HTML elements, such as text nodes. They don't have `classList`. Use `.children` instead of `.childNodes`.

Comment: You don't seem to defined `todoList` anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`childNodes` returns a collection of - as it sounds like - child *nodes*. Some of these nodes may not be elements, but text nodes - and text nodes have no `classList` property. For example:

```js
const childNodes = document.querySelector('.container').childNodes;
console.log(childNodes[0].classList);
console.log(childNodes[1].classList);
```

```html
<div class="container">text node<span>element</span></div>
```

Use `.children` instead, which will retrieve only child *elements*.

```
function filterTodo(e) {
  [...todoList.children].forEach(function (todo) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use.children instead of .childNodes. That should make the error message disappear